# Google Chart: material column chart, last column has different set of colors, using series

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm new to google chart, so my apology if this question is too noobs of me,

i have a material column chart with 2 bars each column, and i want the 2 bars at the last column to have a different color, and i dont want these color to be seen on the legend.i know i should use series for this, but i dont know how to construct it.

currenty what i have is:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawchart);

function drawchart(){
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

          ['Year', 'bar1', { role: 'annotation'}, 'bar2', { role: 'annotation'}],
          ['2015', 90, '90%', 69, '69%'],
          ['2016', 86, '86%', 96, '96%'],
          ['2017', 83, '83%', 87, '87%'],
          ['2018', 84, '84%', 78, '78%'],
          ['AVERAGE', 86, '86%', 82, '82%'],
        ]);

        var options = {
            height:500,
             vAxis: {
             gridlines: {count: 12},
               viewWindow: { max: 120, min: 0 } ,
               textStyle: { color: 'white' }
            },

      seriesType: 'bars' ,
       series: {4:{colors: ['green', 'yellow']}}, 
      legend: {position: 'bottom'},
       annotations: { 
        textStyle: { fontSize: 18, bold: true }
     }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart-div'));
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
    {suffix:'%', fractionDigits: 0});
formatter.format(datasecond, 1); // Apply formatter to second column
formatter.format(datasecond, 3);
        chart.draw(datasecond, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
    }
```

[click here to see the image of my goal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up4x8.png)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `'style'` column role to change the color of individual bars.
add the style to the data table, similar to annotations,
use null for the values that should be the default style

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Year', 'bar1', {role: 'annotation'}, {role: 'style'}, 'bar2', {role: 'annotation'}, {role: 'style'}],
  ['2015', 90, '90%', null, 69, '69%', null],
  ['2016', 86, '86%', null, 96, '96%', null],
  ['2017', 83, '83%', null, 87, '87%', null],
  ['2018', 84, '84%', null, 78, '78%', null],
  ['AVERAGE', 86, '86%', '#109618', 82, '82%', '#ff9900'],
]);
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'bar1', {role: 'annotation'}, {role: 'style'}, 'bar2', {role: 'annotation'}, {role: 'style'}],
    ['2015', 90, '90%', null, 69, '69%', null],
    ['2016', 86, '86%', null, 96, '96%', null],
    ['2017', 83, '83%', null, 87, '87%', null],
    ['2018', 84, '84%', null, 78, '78%', null],
    ['AVERAGE', 86, '86%', '#109618', 82, '82%', '#ff9900'],
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      top: 64,
      left: 64,
      right: 32,
      bottom: 48
    },
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    vAxis: {
      gridlines: {count: 12},
      viewWindow: {max: 120, min: 0} ,
      textStyle: {color: 'white'}
    },
    seriesType: 'bars',
    legend: {position: 'bottom'},
    annotations: {
      textStyle: {fontSize: 18, bold: true}
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart-div'));
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    suffix:'%',
    fractionDigits: 0
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);
  formatter.format(data, 3);
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.chart {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="chart" id="chart-div"></div>
```

---

note: you're actually using a *classic* chart, not *material*

```
google.visualization.ComboChart
```

*material* charts use namespace --> `google.charts`
*classic* --> `google.visualization`

probably shouldn't use `google.charts.Bar.convertOptions` with a *classic* chart...